# decode json with dynamic coding keys

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a JSON file that contains details about cryptocurrency with a key that changes (you can see after data there are 1,2 and so on)
I did some research and realized that I need to use a dictionary (as defined in struct coin info) the problem is that I get an error - "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlying error: nil))

I would appreciate an explanation of what the problem is and where I am wrong.

my structs:

```
struct CoinsInfo:Codable {
    
    
    let data:[String:CoinSpecificInfo]?
  
}

struct CoinSpecificInfo:Codable {
    let urls:UrlsCoins?
    let logo:String?
    let id:Int?
    let symbol:String?
    

}

struct UrlsCoins:Codable {
    
    let website:[CoinWebsites]?
    let twitter:[CoinTwitters]?
    let facebook:[CoinFacebook]?
    let explorer:[CoinExplorer]?
    let reddit:[CoinReddits]?
    
    
}
struct CoinWebsites:Codable {
    
    let website:String?
    
}
struct CoinTwitters:Codable {
    
    let urlTwitters:String?
    
}
struct CoinFacebook:Codable {
    
    let urlFacebook:String?
    
}
struct CoinExplorer:Codable {
    
    
    let urlExplorer:String?
    
}
struct CoinReddits:Codable {
    
    let urlEReddits:String?
    
}
```

json format:

```
{
   "status":{
      "timestamp":"2022-10-09T11:11:11.686Z",
      "error_code":0,
      "error_message":null,
      "elapsed":1,
      "credit_count":1,
      "notice":null
   },
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "urls":{
            "website":[
               "pthkfb543fm",
               "49xjybh5mlq",
               "0uux1lvt44id",
               "kqb4lyfeos",
               "rbh8ui7r9dj",
               "0em815h34ay9",
               "zhmg6phhpmd",
               "z6smii44j5",
               "59bf5ofx2h4",
               "95l4hn2qvr6"
            ],
            "technical_doc":[
               "oid34tehsbb",
               "d1ofa6b2hbg",
               "9l1xpu1bo7",
               "ped2a98gup",
               "y951pv6v55e",
               "9tqxaa6capo",
               "hssug4slmc6",
               "28ocf6dnc3i",
               "cddlngcaboe",
               "xka0x1dijb"
            ],
            "twitter":[
               
            ],
            "reddit":[
               "sbv1ndmtcb",
               "wlu5zd1d2jq",
               "o2b8f0xek3",
               "70l3icwp1sd",
               "pmcm26nvg7d",
               "xz4idaq8at",
               "utaqexwga6",
               "px7o0o4e2f",
               "ginsnepn93i",
               "mqfaedmq29"
            ],
            "message_board":[
               "umt9tn7giq",
               "n37dd8jqkq",
               "b8j4r5gdoio",
               "9hsoy1y579b",
               "twexsn7t5di",
               "v52nrhmnrc",
               "jy5hui32j8k",
               "sssb806c71m",
               "t8sm0f2i1t",
               "tm5osp7fstg"
            ],
            "announcement":[
               
            ],
            "chat":[
               
            ],
            "explorer":[
               "opde5rdke6",
               "r6qhe54rmpl",
               "eoj3z1xqssm",
               "i09e7oxtj1b",
               "rfah6o4912n",
               "jrju212ljoo",
               "oeyzlewitpi",
               "o8l7lk1tsiq",
               "iwms7fi859p",
               "er098njihii"
            ],
            "source_code":[
               "grkckgsnlxd",
               "nl208dwuitg",
               "f09za84abdw",
               "dq5319hlyag",
               "ycf03rrymip",
               "tf76bcn0w9f",
               "2e0vl41amhw",
               "ztpq27uwj3m",
               "l3j3x6hnx5k",
               "zj1c4cl13j"
            ]
         },
         "logo":"d0ln7k9juc",
         "id":1,
         "name":"blntl59cjh",
         "symbol":"iaeaxzvx5jd",
         "slug":"1y0k474cv1d",
         "description":"i72hjlt621l",
         "date_added":"2022-10-09T11:11:11.686Z",
         "date_launched":"2022-10-09T11:11:11.686Z",
         "tags":[
            "n2jbg87vff",
            "vr7mthp6s7",
            "0vbnftw8hqz",
            "h2vhpc39dwf",
            "ocdozsqcv3",
            "0sry86fib7k9",
            "nqkgqwmhon",
            "a6hlvwuv7o",
            "n37q9hsx66a",
            "8edmkawhdlq"
         ],
         "platform":null,
         "category":"w4w9ris8y9p"
      },
      "2":{
         "urls":{
            "website":[
               "3fnvimztsqo",
               "obpgb3o03qc",
               "3rzbwjniljp",
               "lwzp3g0l7qn",
               "pj9i9esmycd",
               "rxxqdzsh74h",
               "c3h167i3gn9",
               "nhztuwzrbqo",
               "lu7gi5qm4fq",
               "pmxizdq4j1"
            ],
            "technical_doc":[
               "ucnmd1rwgji",
               "zxqw8ajty5",
               "tihr9s3f69",
               "l3ba21297z",
               "54kuohb05xn",
               "ml74ors5ltc",
               "utnqamn2ud9",
               "4wg8lcx8pbr",
               "abhp5ohx12b",
               "4fc1smpj5ps"
            ],
            "twitter":[
               
            ],
            "reddit":[
               "alimp4er63t",
               "urpga0uwill",
               "dl68fd2bq8f",
               "vp8mgbjcbv",
               "w6p16dbnv5s",
               "q8dvzg90d",
               "1dkfx8g4f1ui",
               "oederkt3df",
               "00d49eblt6j3l",
               "ywcnpmio49s"
            ],
            "message_board":[
               "cqoizsyx8mn",
               "vqxjb3g2y2r",
               "9oadavn71xm",
               "ew9qubh8x4n",
               "czbbkpt4egu",
               "jbx26vqega",
               "kynzrmrazae",
               "s5twwsy7bw",
               "rw7oep10pj",
               "xqoyj0kc79q"
            ],
            "announcement":[
               
            ],
            "chat":[
               
            ],
            "explorer":[
               "ioac8iuqyma",
               "v9xm5fpid7",
               "hssvwnwhe17",
               "9o77col8hk4",
               "b6tr44woibq",
               "3zoyuxe9s2z",
               "eeh948ksf9o",
               "qdhnncab0po",
               "z80tc2ztsh",
               "xki8g0zw8vh"
            ],
            "source_code":[
               "q5njdmu1tvp",
               "rswxz9717k",
               "fchf720dx3",
               "rzzfhi5mk3g",
               "t3qzejl5gt",
               "qm22rerkrc",
               "11lgg2etg4l",
               "0dru9zhnof7",
               "l2x2n8ueq0c",
               "z33p76whb7c"
            ]
         },
         "logo":"jywrmmc68g",
         "id":2,
         "name":"uiyzzwog9d",
         "symbol":"gy73ckf5l1v",
         "slug":"ki7li2ah6l",
         "description":"o7v6hhf1qce",
         "date_added":"2022-10-09T11:11:11.686Z",
         "date_launched":"2022-10-09T11:11:11.686Z",
         "tags":[
            "157427ygz4v",
            "u5iba7d9yt",
            "89xtswitklk",
            "l8mwl50329c",
            "av0ty13yxi8",
            "27luj3irtrj",
            "6bqwzp1w7lr",
            "7zusdyi69od",
            "kwxa2knt0dn",
            "hpsc19nhm67"
         ],
         "platform":null,
         "category":"1jrjafok03s"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show the real json data, what you show is **not json**, all keys must be quoted, that is, `"status": {..}` not `status: {..}`. Which api are you trying to call? Also, as mentioned in your previous question, copy and paste the "real" json data into https://app.quicktype.io/  to get all correct struct models. Does this not work for you?

Comment: i copied the JSON from what i get from rest API get request , I tried using app.quicktype.io it didn't work

Comment: Show us the api. Use `print("\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` to print the response, and show us the results. `app.quicktype.io` did not work because it is not json.

Comment: I edit the post to JSON format

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate an explanation of what the problem is and where I
> am wrong.

The problem is that the *website*, *twitter*, *facebook*, *explorer*, *reddit* keys are arrays of strings in the JSON response not arrays of custom objects so if you change the *UrlsCoins* to:

```
struct UrlsCoins:Codable {

    let website:[String]?
    let twitter:[String]?
    let facebook:[String]?
    let explorer:[String]?
    let reddit:[String]?
}
```

You will be able to parse the JSON